# InfluxDB cannot select field key

Tags: influxdb

I'm new to InfluxDB. I have an existing database with a table `language`. When I run `select * from language` I get the following table:

```
name: language
time                     application_guid application_name application_type instance_index lang metric_type stream_name value
----                     ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- -------------- ---- ----------- ----------- -----
2019-03-07T07:46:49.225Z 31429            counter          sink             0              ar   counter     tweetlang   0
2019-03-07T07:46:49.225Z 31429            counter          sink             0              ca   counter     tweetlang   0
2019-03-07T07:46:49.225Z 31429            counter          sink             0              de   counter     tweetlang   0
2019-03-07T07:46:49.225Z 31429            counter          sink             0              el   counter     tweetlang   0
```

When I run `select "lang" from language` I get an empty result. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/select-tag-and-value-from-measurment/1485):

> The SELECT clause must specify at least one field when it includes a
>   tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Select Clause](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-basic-select-statement)  can be given to field key and possible to give query with field name and tag key together  where tag key is for indexing and field is what you defined as a column in the measurement.

If a select query will be given by a tag name, it won't return any result.

According to your measurement named `language` has `lang` key as a tag key.

if we consider your `field names` as follows:

`application_guid application_name application_type instance_index`

And `tags` as given below:

`lang metric_type stream_name value`

The select query can be given like these ways:

`select *  from language`

`select application_guid,lang from language`

if multiple field and tags you want to give in the statement then:

`select application_guid,application_type::field, metric_type,stream_name::tag   from language`

In addition, InfluxDb uses Line protocol, where line protocol informs InfluxDB of the data’s measurement, tag set, field set, and timestamp.